# how to fetch all rows data from the database using while loop and stored fetch values in variables in php

Tags: php, html

hi everyone i have table in the database from where i fetch data one column of table has user input n i fetch the data on the basis of user input like if user enter 2 in the textbox only that rows that contain number 2 will display 
like 
code of insertion on the basis of no of room

```
   <?php
    $d=$_POST['roomno'];
    echo $d;
    ?>
      <?php
      //database connection
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ems",'root','');
    //query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (c,c1, c2, c3, c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13) VALUES ('',:c1, :c2, :c3, :c4,:c5, :c6, :c7, :c8, :c9,:c10, :c11, :c12,'$d')";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($data_t1 as $i => $value) {
        $stmt->execute(array(
           ':c1'=>$data_t1[$i],
           ':c2'=>$data_t2[$i],
           ':c3'=>$data_t3[$i],
           ':c4'=>$data_t4[$i],
           ':c5'=>$data_t11[$i],
           ':c6'=>$data_t22[$i],
           ':c7'=>$data_t33[$i],
           ':c8'=>$data_t44[$i],
           ':c9'=>$data_t111[$i],
           ':c10'=>$data_t222[$i],
           ':c11'=>$data_t333[$i],
           ':c12'=>$data_t444[$i],
        ));
    } ?>
```

coding for fetchng the data

```
 <?php
    include('config.php');
    $sa="select * from table1 where c13='$d'";
    $result=mysql_query($sa) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>

    </tr>";

     <?php
    $i = 1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       echo ${"r" . $i . "1"} = $row['c'];
      echo  ${"r" . $i . "2"} = $row['c1'] ;
       echo ${"r" . $i . "3"} = $row['c2'];
       echo ${"r" . $i . "4"} = $row['c3'];
       echo ${"r" . $i . "5"} = $row['c4'];
       $i++;
    }
```

result

```
$d=3;mean user enter 3
3 room deatils enter in three rows of table like ths

row1  2   4  5   6    3(user enter value)
row2  12  14 15   16   3(user enter value)
row3  22  44  55  63   3(user enter value)
```

now as i mention in my fetch query that fetch the data where c13(room)=user input($d);

result of theses above three row display

now i want to store each of theses three row values in different varaibles

in the similar manner if user enter 2 or 4 i want to store two or four rows values in different varaible

Comment: Consider using `mysqli_` functions instead of the old `mysql_` as these old functions are soon to be discontinued and your programs will stop working if the host upgrades the platform..

Comment: …or use PDO. Anyway, it's better to switch to [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommand you to use Michael Sazonov's way.. but if you don't want arrays here you go:

```
<?php
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   ${"r" . $i . "1"} = $row['c'];
   ${"r" . $i . "2"} = $row['c1'] ;
   ${"r" . $i . "3"} = $row['c2'];
   ${"r" . $i . "4"} = $row['c3'];
   ${"r" . $i . "5"} = $row['c4'];
   $i++;
}
```

Now The contents are stored in $r11 $r12 $r13.. $r35 and you have to echo them manually or using 2 for loops

```
<?php
for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++) {
   for($j=0; $j<=5; $j++) {
      echo ${'r'.$i.$j};
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course it will display only the last row. Within each iteration over the query result you are rewriting the `$r` -nth variable, so the result you'll see after the loop are only the values that were assigned during the last iteration.

Use

```
$row = array();
while($row[] = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
}
```

As result you will get all the data stored as an array in `$row`.
What it does is as follows:
Iterates over the query result and and fetching it. The fetching method returns an array of the current iterated row values. This array is pushed into the `$row` array. So, each row value could be accessed at a corresponding index of `$row`.
Use `print_r( $row );` to see the structure.

Further use of the array is as follows:

```
echo $row[ 0 ][ 'c1' ];
echo $row[ 0 ][ 'c2' ];
echo $row[ 1 ][ 'c3' ];
```

If you want to show the input depending on a dynamical rows amount, use this:

```
$count = count( $row );
for( $i = 0 ; $i < $count; $i++ ){
    echo $row[ $i ][ 'c1' ];
}
```

Comment: sir i dont want to use array as i want these values  to be used for further computataion

Comment: @user2421659 Array is a set of values. Or am I missing something in your question?

Comment: sir your are rite that array are set of values but i need to store every value in some varaible instead to store in whole array

Comment: sir if 2 is present in 3 rows then how could be its is possible? here you mention $row[0] indicx of array

Comment: @user2421659 I've edited the answer. Try this method and use the `print_r` to see the structure. Then you should understand how to handle it.

Comment: sir how can i store each n every fectch value in different varaibles

Comment: Ider Aghbal suggested a solution for this kind of question.

Comment: @user2421659 That's one the answers on this page +)

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
$data = array() ; //Declare an array
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $data[] = $row ; //Add every row to array
}

echo $data['c4'] ; // Work with the array ETC
```

Comment: sir i need to perform further computation can't i store the value in varaibles $r=$row?